# How to get return value of invoked method?

Tags: java, reflection

I'm trying to achieve some sort of reflection in java. 
I have:

```
class P {
  double t(double x) {
    return x*x;
  }

  double f(String name, double x) {
    Method method;
    Class<?> enclosingClass = getClass().getEnclosingClass();
     if (enclosingClass != null) {
        method = enclosingClass.getDeclaredMethod(name, x);
        try {
          method.invoke(this, x);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

class o extends P {
  double c() { 
    return f("t", 5);
  }
}
```

How do I get value from new o().c()?

Comment: Did you check the return value of `method.invoke(this, x);` ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Putting the dummy class for your reference, you can change your code accordingly-

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Dummy {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(new Dummy().f("t", 5));
    }

    double t(Double x) {
        return x * x;
    }

    double f(String name, double x) throws Exception {
        double d = -1;
        Method method;
        Class<?> enclosingClass = getClass();
        if (enclosingClass != null) {
            method = enclosingClass.getDeclaredMethod(name, Double.class);
            try {
                Object value = method.invoke(this, x);
                d = (Double) value;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return d;
    }
}
```

Just run this class.

Comment: Fixed that. I'm getting exception: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - unreported exception java.lang.Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown"

Comment: You need to handle the exception. Put the calling code in the try-catch block.

Comment: Now I'm getting NoSuchMethodException

Comment: Are you trying with the code that I pasted here? Also, always better to post the complete stack trace, its easy to figure out the issue then.

Comment: I just updated the answer with the Dummy class, run it and use it as a reference to change your code.

Answer (score 5):

`invoke()` method returns the object which is returned after that method execution! so you can try...

```
Double dd = (Double)method.invoke(this,x);
double retunedVal = dd.doubleValue();
```