# How to get the methods that return the class members?

Tags: java, class, object, methods

I want to know if I can get the methods that returns class members.

For example I have a class called `Person` inside this class there is two members that are `name` and `age` and inside this class I have 4 methods as follow :

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

so if I use the method `Person.class.getDeclaredMethods();` it returns all the methods that are declared inside this class and also `Person.class.getDeclaredMethods()[0].getReturnType();` returns the return type of the method.

**But** what I need is to get the methods that returns the two variables `name` and `age` In this case the methods are `public String getName()` and `public int getAge()`.

What can I do?

Comment: Define _global variables_.

Comment: Those are not global variables, they are member variables of the class.

Comment: **global variables** are `Name` and `Age`

Comment: You don't mean global variables

Comment: In your class `name` and `age` **are not** global. They would need to have a `static` before them to be global. Also, to "get" them you'd need methods that start with "get".

Comment: I give full explanation,, its not matter what you name them

Comment: @Sam It is.. That's how you learn, we're here to help and correct each others.

Comment: @Sam This link might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15697217/how-to-get-return-value-of-invoked-method

Comment: @Tom sorry it was a mistake

Comment: What do you intend to do with that information?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I'm building a method that takes input of any object and saves the variables of this object inside a file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your class `name` and `age` **are not** global. They would need to have a `static` before them to be global. In order to access your fields with an instance and reflection you could do something like

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Person p = new Person("Elliott", 37);
    Field[] fields = p.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field f : fields) {
        try {
            f.setAccessible(true);
            String name = f.getName();
            String val = f.get(p).toString();
            System.out.printf("%s = %s%n", name, val);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Output is (as I would expect)

```
name = Elliott
age = 37
```

Comment: @Sam Note that the above is accessing the fields directly; it's also possible to call through the methods but it's a bit more complicated - especially if you want the member values themselves.

Comment: yeah actually I want the member values of any object if it possible

Comment: That's what this code gives you.